# How do I return Cloudfront url after S3 upload?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a file to an S3 bucket for which I've created a Cloudfront distribution. I'm using the `Aws\S3\S3Client` class.

After uploading with `putObject`, the response object and the `getObjectUrl` method both return the object's url as https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/path/myfile.jpg. I am trying to get the Cloudfront url which would be something like https://d111111111ck.cloudfront.net/path/myfile.jpg.

Is there any way to get this url directly, or do I have to build it from my distribution hostname and file path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't get a cloudfront URL from S3, it's a different service. If your using `putObject` then you already know the file path (value specified in `Key`).

Just return the cloudfront URL in front of the file path e.g...

```
$filePath = '/path/file.jpg';

$client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key' => $filePath,
    'SourceFile' => $fileSource,
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
));

return 'https://d111111111ck.cloudfront.net' . $filePath;
```

Comment: right, so I guess there's is no way to resolve an associated cloudfront url for the bucket. I'll just have to store it in the config.

Comment: that is correct, you could use the `getDistribution` method in the `Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient` class to return the domain but you have to know the ID so you may as well store the domain in config!

Answer (score 0):

`I guess there's is no way to resolve an associated cloudfront url for the bucket`. Yes, It is!

**CloudFront** is a **CDN caching**. You did not need to get the URL to s3 bucket/file because CloudFront cares about this for you.

More details about [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) here.

Follow the steps and see the `step 24`. That's it!

**Screenshots below:**

[image]
[image]

Enjoy! :)